# SCP Policies for Amazon RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I would like to create a Service Control Policies (SCP) policy at the Organization Level that can block 3 things:

- Don't allow creating a database **Publicly Accessible**
- Don't allow creating a database without the option of **encryption** marked
- Don't allow creating a database without the option of **backup** marked

Anyone know if is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can now create a Service Control Policy (SCP) to prevent unencrypted RDS databases from being created using the [`rds:StorageEncrypted`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonrds.html#amazonrds-rds_StorageEncrypted) condition:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Condition": {
        "Bool": {
          "rds:StorageEncrypted": "false"
        }
      },
      "Action": [
        "rds:CreateDBInstance",
        "rds:CreateDBCluster"
      ],
      "Resource": "*",
      "Effect": "Deny"
    }
  ]
}
```

You still can't create an SCP to prevent public access or no backup policy as far as I know because there aren't any [condition keys](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonrds.html#amazonrds-policy-keys) to help you filter for those conditions.

Comment: This is a good start but Aurora users may need to add more conditions and statements, according to https://medium.com/@mattgillard/how-to-enforce-encryption-on-aws-rds-the-correct-way-4c55251ce40e

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that Service Control Policies can act at this level.

They basically say which API calls are permitted (eg `CreateDbInstance`, `RebootDbInstance`) and don't get down to the level of parameters.

In fact, I don't think it would be possible to create *normal* IAM policies that have that level of detail, let alone SCPs.

Such rules would likely need to be monitored by [Evaluating Resources with AWS Config Rules - AWS Config](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/evaluate-config.html) rather than controlling permissions.